# Как контролировать объем изображения?

Tags: delphi, изображения

Здравствуйте! При сохранении изображения

```
Image1.Picture.SaveToFile(Edit1.Text+inttostr(i) +Edit2.Text);
```

таким не мудреным образом, возник вопрос: как контролировать объем изображения? 
Мне нужно, чтобы изображение весело не более 65 КБ. Как такое можно реализовать?

Comment: перемножьте ширину на высоту да на глубину цвета, плюс накиньте длину заголовка и палитры.

Comment: Мне нужно что бы при этом не изменялись размеры изображения.

Comment: Вы хотите чтобы картинка любого размера после сохранения была не больше 65Кб? Так не бывает.

Comment: Вроде бы у EFG было исследование о зависимости размера JPEG файла от коэффициента сжатия...

Answer (score 1):

Изменяйте глубину палитры, св-во `PixelFormat`. По умолчанию стоит `pf32Bit`, можно установить в `pf24Bit` без потери качества, также неплохой результат дает `pf15Bit`. Ну а если и этого мало, то сделайте свой алгоритм уменьшения количества цветов в палитре. Меньше цветов - меньше размер.